# Can I iterate through a p tag and change to an ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a script that iterates through a paragraph with several sentences of text and inserts a li tag at the start and at the end of each sentence. Is this possible?

So, turning this paragraph

```
<p>
   Give your work the edge with this pencil. Awesome design, and chunky gold finish. Get the look. 
</p>
```

into this unordered list

```
<p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Give your work the edge with this pencil.
    </li> 
    <li>
      Awesome design, and chunky gold finish. 
    </li>
    <li>
      Get the look. 
    </li>
  </ul>
</p>
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. Have you tried anything yet? We won't be able to help you if you are just waiting for the code all set :-)

Comment: Yeah, possible.  Use the period as line delimiter when parsing the text.

Comment: While it's possible, note that `<ul>` is not valid inside `<p>` so you probably shouldn't be doing it. Change the `<p>` to a `<div>` as well.

Comment: @MichaelLumbroso apologies, yes, I was scratching around using indexOf which clearly wasn't going to work so I didn't post it. I should have said this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('p').each(function() {
  var $par = $(this),
      theText = $par.text().split('. ');
  $par.text('');
  $.each(theText, function(i, item) {
    if ($.trim(item).length > 0)
      $par.append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
  });
});
```

Untested, but you get the idea. Split, then run through the array, wrapping in your tags.

Comment: To add the period back in, put it before `</li>`. `split()` will remove whatever parameter is passed in.

Comment: your `theText.each()` function will fail since it's contents are not jQuery Objects,  You need to use $.each to iterate over the array

Comment: Thank you both, that is tremendously helpful. I made a slight edit at the suggestion of @wirey and changed `theText.each()` to `$.each(theText, function(i, item) {`. My final comment is that the array thinks there are four items with the final one being a blank so a bullet point with white space is created.

Comment: @AJH See my edit with `if ($.trim(item).length > 0)`. Please note that `.trim()` is not supported in all browsers, but jQuery's `$.trim()` is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. 
First thing first all you have to do is 
`Tokenize` every paragraph with "." which will separate the paragraph into different sentence and then add li tag in between..

For changing content from p to ul you can use this link ::

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

for tokenize a single para into sentences you can use this :

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-split.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$.each($(".my-content").text().split("."), function(index,item){  

     $(".my-ul").append($("<li/>").text(item));

});
```